# Etymology of "Sort"

Tags: etymology, early-modern-english, french

Did the English word *sort* originate from the French word *sort*?

e.g., *sortie*.

Whereas, in French its meaning derives to *out*, *exit*, *going out*.

How did it end up in English to mean *category*, *class/type*, *arrangement*, *manner/pattern*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Latin *sortiri* meant: "to select", "to choose by lot". And it retained that meaning in Old French *sortir*. *Sortir* took the meaning of "to exit" in the 16th century, so long after the French and their language had invaded Britain. (The OED provides an example of the use of "sort" in English in a sentence by Chaucer dated 1374).
 Up to the 16th century Old French *essir* (*issir*) was used to express the movement of going out. French *issue* (hence the English *issue* meaning *exit*) come from that Old French *issir*.

So the origin of the word **sort** in English seems pretty straightforward. What is less straightforward is how the word took the meaning of *go out* in Modern French. Various assumptions are made. Will try and post something on that on [FL&U](http://french.stackexchange.com).

---

I posted something in Fl&U [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12104686#12104686).

Comment: Maybe at the French bars, whenever a fight broke out, the bar tender would yell, "Go outside and sort it out!" So frequent were bar-fights that the bar keepers simply yelled "sort it out", which  would then imply "Get outside". Just kidding.

Answer (score 1):

It originated from Middle English which in turn came from Old French which in turn originated from Latin. Here's a description of its origin from Google.

[image]

Comment: Who down-voted? Why?